# What is the minimum norm of this vector?(please check my answer.)

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

The Linear mapping $T : \mathbb{R^3} \to \mathbb{R^3}$ with its Eigenvalues $0$ and $2$. The Eigenvectors is $v _1 = (0,1,1)$ for $2$. The Eigenvector are $v_2=(1,1,0)$ and $v_3= (1,0,1)$ for $0$.  Find the minimum of the $x^2+y^2+z^2$ satisfying the $T((x,y,z)) = (0,2,2)$.

I put the $X =(x,y,z)$. Then, $X = v_1 + av_2 + bv_3$  since the $ker(T) = <v_2 , v_3>$ ($a,b \in \mathbb{R}$)

So the $(x,y,z) = (a+b, a+1, b+1)$ $\Rightarrow$ $\Vert X \Vert = \sqrt{2(a^2 + ab+ b^2 +1)}$

My answer is $\sqrt 2$ for the $a=b=0$ case.

Is my answer right?

Comment: Consider $a=-\frac12$, $b=0$ and do the calculations again.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\mathbf{X}=a_1 \mathbf{v_1} + a_2 \mathbf{v_2} + a_3 \mathbf{v_3}$ such that $T(\mathbf{X})= \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\2 \\2\end{bmatrix}$.

$$
\begin{aligned}
T(\mathbf{X}) &= \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\2 \\2\end{bmatrix} \\
T(a_1 \mathbf{v_1} + a_2 \mathbf{v_2} + a_3 \mathbf{v_3}) &= \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\2 \\2\end{bmatrix} \\
a_1 T(\mathbf{v_1}) + a_2 T(\mathbf{v_2}) + a_3 T(\mathbf{v_3})&= \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\2 \\2\end{bmatrix} \\
a_1\cdot 2 \cdot \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\1 \\1\end{bmatrix}&=\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\2 \\2\end{bmatrix}
\end{aligned}
$$

Therefore, $a_1=1$

Plug in $a_1=1$:

$$
\begin{aligned}
\mathbf{X}=\mathbf{v_1} + a_2 \mathbf{v_2} + a_3 \mathbf{v_3} \\
\mathbf{X}=\begin{bmatrix} a_2 + a_3\\ a_2+1\\ a_3+1\end{bmatrix} \\
\end{aligned}
$$

Hence,

$$
||\mathbf{X}||^2
=2 (a_2^2+ a_3^2 + a_2 a_3 + a_2+a_3 +1)
$$
It is different from your one.